# changing default to function django

Tags: python, django, default-value

so im trying to change the default language according to a setting a user made before. My problem is that the value of the function im calling is 'English' or 'Spanish' but I need a short term like 'en' or 'esp' to make it actually work. I also have this error message when I try to try to run it: userlang() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

so here is what I tried:

```
def userlang(self):
    return (self.user.userprofile.language)

class 123(models.Model
    language = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u"Language"), 
               max_length=4, choices=settings.LANGUAGES,default=userlang)
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: that is what I tried first but it does not work because I get userlang is not defined. The name is not the original one I changed it for the Post but thank you :)

Comment: Use it as you have it and remove `self` parameter from the `userlang` function. Of course, this will not work, because you are referencing `self` inside it. A workaround to this is to remove the `default` (or keep it and set it with one from the `LANGUAGES` choices) and override the [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) method and set inside there the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use such a thing:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    language = gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=(('en', 'English'),('es', 'Spanish')),
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Then it's pretty straight forward to use.

Of course if you have hundred of possibilities for the language, you should do a OneToMany association and not using such a pattern.

Btw. Your example is very badly formatted and written. For the error you have, just remove "self" in the arguments of your function... It's only required when it's class method.